# Publishing a Firefox addon without Mozilla's consent

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I am wondering if it is possible to self host a Firefox addon instead of going through Mozilla. I would like users to be able to install the addon from my website, and bypass the approval and hosting of Mozilla.

The reason is the addon would violate the [updated review policy](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2010/03/30/add-on-review-policy-update/) because of advertising. The users would know this, and the addon would follow the rest of Mozilla's [policies](https://preview.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/submission) fully (except for it is only useful for a very small niche).

Basically, the users will be rewarded in a web application (think runescape gold) for having small text-link ads from our partners/sponsors displayed during regular browsing. They will be able to turn off the ads whenever they want.

**So heres the question**
What do I need to do in order to have my addon installed from a regular website? Is it even possible? Is it illegal? Will Firefox allow it to be installed? Does it need a signature to be installed?

**Moral Note:**
This is something the users will want, choose, and be rewarded for. I know ads on browsers are evil, but every dog has its day.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can host an add-on anywhere; the user will be asked if they want to allow your site to install software.  Whether it's illegal is a matter to discuss with your attorney.

Comment: I think it would only be illegal if your site or add-on did something illegal by law. It's just that your add-on violates review policy which only affect publishing on Mozilla's site as I understand it. Mozilla does not forbid add-ons of any type as I know it - it's in the users' responsibility to take care of their systems.